# How to share an object (e.g. instance of Zend_Auth) between multiple controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have my application within Zend Framework 1. I'm using Zend_Auth to manage sessions. Below is how I check authentication within the IndexController class:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
      $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

      if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $this->view->user = $auth->getIdentity();
      }
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

}
```

Basically it just sets a view variable of user to whatever is in the auth object. Within my view I can check if the user variable is set and act appropriately (e.g. Display "Welcome Tom!" and a logout link)

However, this functionality is not available yet in my other controllers. Rather than duplicate the same code within each init() method, how can I do this? I'm not so sure where to put the code for this.

UPDATE:

I tried to do something like this in the bootstrap file:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
  protected function _initView() {
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
      $this->view->user = $auth->getIdentity();
    }
  }
}
```

..but I get the following error: `Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Bootstrap::$view has no effect in /var/www/budgetz/application/Bootstrap.php on line 9 Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/budgetz/application/Bootstrap.php on line 9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an abstract class inheriting from `Zend_Controller_Action` like this:

```
abstract Class Yourlibrary_Controller_ControllerAbstract extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $this->view->user = $auth->getIdentity();
        }
    }
}
```

And yours Controllers inherit `Yourlibrary_Controller_ControllerAbstract` not `Zend_Controller_Action`

Comment: Does the preDispatch() function run automatically? Somewhat like init() in my example?

Comment: Yes. For a controller, the order of methods is : Init() -> preDispatch() -> Action() -> postDispatch().

Comment: Hi again. Sorry maybe I don't really understand how the autoloader works - I created a file called ControllerAbstract.php with a class called My_Controller_ControllerAbstract in folder ProjectDir/library/My/Controller/. However, I get an error saying class not found. Have I put it in the wrong place?

Comment: It seem correct. have yo add `autoloadernamespaces[] = "My"` in your application.ini (to add your My library)

Comment: No, I hadn't. First time to create a new namespace. It's working now, thanks

Comment: Happy for you.:) And Good Luck!